# Customize autoform array display template

Tags: arrays, meteor

I am working with autoform and have a hard time try to customize array inserting template.
If I use {{> afQuickField name='POs'}} POs is defined in simpleschema as an array with 4 fields.
This way works fine, showing the form with add more element button shown and every thing which is really COOL!
But each field of POs takes the whole line like:

```
field 1:_____________________________________

field 2:_____________________________________

field 3:_____________________________________

field 4:_____________________________________
```

But I am trying to make four fields in same line like:
field 1: field 2: field 3: field 4:

In summary I am trying to customize this display template 
I have tried:

```
{{#afEachArrayItem name='POs'}}

{{> afFieldInput name='this.current.field1'}}

{{> afFieldInput name='this.current.field2l'}}

{{/afEachArrayItem}}
```

but it does not work for me

Can someone help me on this problem?

//here is the schema for one PO

`Schemas.eachPOSchema=new SimpleSchema({
poNum:{
  type:String,
  label:"P/O Num",
  },
model:{
  type:String,
  label:"Model"
},
singlePrice:{
  type:Number,
  decimal:true,
  label:"Price"
},
quantity:{
  type:Number,
  label:"Quantity"
}
 })`

//and this is POs schema that stores POs in array

`Schemas.POsSchema=new SimpleSchema({
POs:{
    type:[Schemas.eachPOSchema],
    minCount:2,
},
 totalPrice:{
  type:Number,
  decimal:true,
   },
 attachCI:{
  type:Boolean,
 },
 attachPC:{
  type:Boolean,
 },
 attachQA:{
  type:Boolean,
 },
 attachISF:{
  type:Boolean,
 },
 attachBOL:{
  type:Boolean,
 },
 estimateShipTime:{
  type:Date,
 }
})`

//for front end I tried quickForm,it gives me the functionalists, but I want to customize the layout of the output

`{{#quickForm collection="pos" id="posForm" tyep="insert"}}
{{/quickForm}}`

Comment: Can you include example code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have just updated my question. Hope is more clear now thanks lot